# ffmpeg concat discards audio stream

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, concatenation

***What I want to achieve***
I have two input videos which I do want to concatenate using ffmpeg.

***Issue***
The input videos contain two stereo audio channels:
[image]

after concatenation, the second audio stream is lost:
[image]

***steps to reproduce***
The Command I used is

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c:a copy -c:v copy demuxed.mp4
```

***Additional Information***
The Console Output shows the second audio stream in input properly:
[image]

The Output settings also show that there is only one audio output stream. But I want to have the exact same settings in to out, just concatenated:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that all input videos have matching audio streams, add mapping.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:a copy -c:v copy demuxed.mp4
```

See http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection, especially the section on automatic stream selection for details on how ffmpeg selects streams.

Comment: thank you so much. Do you know if it is possible to do the command without an input file list? when trying `ffmpeg -f -i "concat:0.mp4|1.mp4" -map 0 -c:a copy -c:v copy demuxed2.mp4` I receive wrong output format error

Comment: No, the text file list is required.